# QML Connection and IDE - new syntax: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated

Tags: qt, ide, qml, qt-design-studio

In the new version of QML 1.5.0, it is recommended to use the new syntax for **connection** e.g.

```
MouseArea {
Connections {
    function onClicked (mouse) {foo (mouse)}
}
```

Using the "Qt Design Studio 1.5.0" or "Qt Creator 4.12.1" IDE
I get this warning.

With the old syntax, connections are visible in the *Form Editor -> Connection View*  window and nothing is displayed there after the change 
for a new one.

Form Editor -> Connection with old syntax.

[image]

Being in a UI file e.g. main.ui.qml

Old syntax:

I receive a message:

```
Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo (<arguments>) {...}
```

After correcting for the new syntax, the message is: *Function are not supported on a Qt Quick UI Form. (M22).* and now is no possibility to edit the window using Form Editor.

I also can't make a connection to property e.g.

```
property bool mouseEnable: false

Connections {
    target: parent
    function onMouseEnableChanged(parent)
}
```

This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name.

It is possible to stay with the old syntax without displaying a warning 
or maybe someone knows how to use the new syntax without the above IDE errors?